# Android FrameLayout makes "invisible" margins

Tags: android, android-framelayout

I have a FrameLayout and I want to have as much small as possible. But that layout gives me some invisible margins from top and bottom. That's how it looks:

[image]

And should look:

[image]

My FrameLayout looks like that:

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivPress"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/custom" />

        <com.devadvance.circularseekbar.CircularSeekBar
            android:id="@+id/circularSeekBar1"
            app:circle_x_radius="147"
            app:circle_y_radius="147"
            app:use_custom_radii="true"
            app:max="100"
            app:pointer_alpha_ontouch="100"
            app:pointer_color="#ffffff"
            app:pointer_halo_color="#ffffff"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvResult"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Tap!"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="50dp" />

      </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: use a hierarchviewer to see all the view bounds and you will see that thrtre is no margin at all

Comment: I know there isn't any margins, but there is an empty space in top and bottom. How can I remove it?

Comment: did you run hierarchyviewer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me confirm my understanding is correct.

1. Blue gradation image is set to ImageView(ivPress).
2. CircularSeekBar class decides where draws circle.

If my understanding is true, FrameLayout has no magins. ImageView(ivPress) can be shown without margins.

So, the issue you should solve is that there are margins in top and bottom of circle, right? I don't know how you implement CircularSeekBar class but some problem is in it.